# Discord.js detect double boost and boost cancellation

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to make a discord bot that is capable of detecting when someone boosts a server multiple times and when someone cancells one of their boosts.

The issue im currently facing is that there is no offical documentation on detecting multiple boosts. Ive attempted to use the guildMemberUpdate event however the member update is only updated after an intial boost and no follow up boosts.

The only way to possibly detect a double boost is by listening for a boost message

However how do I detect if one of the boosts is cancelled ?

Since there isnt an update event called

Comment: That is because boost messages/boost cancellations is not an event implemented by discord. There only methods is checking the type of the message and checking if it is a booster message, and to check for a boost cancellation by checking if a booster role is updated.

Comment: There is a user-exclusive `/guilds/{guild.id}/premium/subscriptions` that returns a full list of active boosts for users but throws error 20001 for bots.